Java with RestEasy: @Valid but not just on endpoint
I find myself in the following scenario, in a RestEasy REST API:
@POST
@Path("my-endpoint")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myEndpoint(
    final @Nullable Payload payload
) {
    final var result = runCommand(
      new Command(payload),
      withPermissions(CAN_WRITE)
    );

    return ok(result);
}

...
@Value
public class Payload {
    @NotNull Long mSomeValidLong;
}

...
@Value
public class Command {
    @NotNull @Valid mPayload;
}

As you can see, the endpoint does not validate the payload immediately.
Instead, there is nested logic : the payload is passed to a Command which is then executed by method runCommand.
Even though you can't see how runCommand is implemented, you can see that first it checks the permissions. It also has some fancy logic for worker threads and exception catching.
Bottom line : It is the Command that must validate the parameters, (because that's when we've reached the place where the permissions have been controlled and when we're sure we have the resources for that).
Don't ask me why the permissions are not validated as an @Annotation immediately above the endpoint method, this is legacy code.
With that setup, I observe this :
This works (because RestEasy identifies the method as one of his) :
public Response myEndpoint(final @Valid @NotNull Payload payload) { ... }

This does not work because this is plain old Java :
public Command(final @Valid @NotNull Payload payload) { ... } // Constructor as it would be generated by Lombok

My question : is there any way at all to make @Valid do its magic somewhere else than in the endpoint's method parameters?
From what I read, jakarta.validation would do exactly the same kind of validation in non-RestEasy parts of the code.
Follow-up question : Is it reasonable to have two different competing validation systems? (RestEasy's validation, plus another kind such as Jakarta's validation )

When you instanciate the command with new, Spring has no chance to inject the validators.

In other words: Command isn't a bean managed by spring. Validation with @NotNull or something else just works with spring-manged beans. I guess your endpoint definition is inside an object annotated with @Controlleror similar. In this case validation works on method-parameter-level too.

They are not competing validation systems they are exactly the same. You are also not using Spring MVC but rather Jersey (regardless both support @Valid). However where with Spring MVC it is part of the method execution it isn't when calling regular methods. You can use @Validated on your class to trigger validation on method calls but that won't work here either as the runCommand is an internal method call (and that doesn't work with internal method calls). So as a workaround you could manually do validation or use full blown AspectJ to support internal method calls.

@ThiloSchwarz Is there a simpler annotation than @ Controller to make the framework inject its validation mechanisms into a class? i.e. I don't want to turn Command or the object that has runCommand it into a controller.

@M.Deinum I think we're actually using JAX-RS, not Spring or Jersey. My bad.

@M.Deinum I confirm that we are using RestEasy / JAX-RS.  So, do you maintain that the only way here is to run validation manually on the command?

Adding the @Valid to a constructor won't do anything not for Spring not for Jersey. You can validate method arguments for JAX-RS endpoints or Spring Controllers with it. But it won't work for constructors. If you place it on an another method that is called from a handling method unless you throw in some AOP (as mentioned before) it won't work either.

Was this answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78613823/how-to-correctly-apply-valid? What version of RESTEasy are you using?

@JamesR.Perkins not this is an entirely different question. this question is about manually applying validation in other areas of the code than where it was originally automated.

This could be a solution : How to manually trigger Spring validation?
1. Inject a validator
@Autowired
private Validator validator;

2. Use it manually
validator.validate(myObject);

The validator can be the default validator :
// JSR-303 Validator
import javax.validation.Validator;

...or some fancy validator, for example the validator provided by Spring :
// Spring Validator
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;


replace @Valid with Spring's own @Validated

I will try but I think that's not the issue here. See @M. Deinum 's comment under my question.
