How to correctly apply @Valid?
EDIT: THIS QUESTION IS ENTIRELY INVALID.
I have left it as a cautionary tale to others (see solution)
===================
Supposedly this is the proper way of performing validation on a RestEasy/JAX-RS endpoint when there is no nested object:
@Value
public class PayloadWithNotNull {
    @NotNull Long mSomeLong; // Long is an object, but it's still "Just a long"
}

...

@POST
@Path("test1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test1(
    final @Valid @NotNull PayloadWithNotNull payload
) {
    return ok();
}

Notice how parameter payload has both @Valid and @NotNull, but mSomeLong only has @NotNull.
Here is what I observe depending on the request's JSON body:

Sending null -> 400 with explicit message "test1.payload must not be null"
Sending {} -> 400 without an explicit message
Sending { "someLong": null } -> 400 without an explicit message
Sending { "someLong": "not a long" } -> 400 without an explicit message

However, if I add @Valid on the class field:
@Value
public class PayloadWithValidNotNull {
    @Valid @NotNull Long mSomeLong;
}


Sending null -> 400 with explicit message "test1.payload must not be null"
Sending {} -> 400 with explicit message "test1.payload.someLong must not be null". That's an improvement.
Sending { "someLong": null } -> 400 with explicit message "test1.payload.someLong must not be null". That's an improvement.
Sending { "someLong": "not a long" } -> Still 400 without an explicit message. That is subpar, but consistent.

I was under the impression that @Valid is only required for nested objects. I seem to read that everywhere. And yet, it seems absolutely required for this Long field, which despite being itself an object does not have nested objects.
What is the proper way of using @Valid so that it validates every relevant field and so that it generates a meaningful error message for all the scenarios above?
EDIT :
Quote from the JAX-RS specification ( paragraph 31.2.2 Validating Entity Data  here : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced002.htm )

To validate these entity classes, use the @Valid annotation on the
method parameter.

The example shows @Valid only on the method parameter, not on the @NotNull field inside the object.

The cause of the unexpected HTTP error codes had nothing to do with a misuse of @Valid.
It is simply that the classes should have been declared with keyword static in my tests:
public static class ParentClass { // <-- static!
   public ChildClass child; // @Valid not needed because public property
}

public static class ChildClass { // <-- static !
   public Long someLong;  // @Valid not needed because public property
}

The missing static prevented the validator from instantiating the class (despite a successful parsing) and made it throw InvalidDefinitionException which resulted in a confusing HTTP 400 (false negatives).
After new tests, it turned out that @Valid only needs to be applied at top level (as advertised) and it has nothing to do with the fields/properties being public or private, despite being confusingly brought up by the standard :
Source: https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/

Paragraph 3.1.3. Graph validation
Validation of graphs of object is supported. (...)
Consider the situation where bean X contains a field of type Y. By
annotating field Y with the @Valid annotation, the Validator will
validate Y (and its properties ) when X is validated.

